# "Personal Letter", is that "Personal letter from me" or "Personal letter to you"?

Tags: meaning

I have received a number of emails this christmas, all saying they're a "personal letter". They're all from past online accounts, like online learning services and similar.

I started to ponder the meaning of a "personal letter".

These emails are nothing personal, to me. They're obviously written by a person on the other end, but aren't all emails? (by "all" here I obviously mean all emails written by people...)

So the question is this;

What is the definition of the concept of a "personal letter"?

- Is it a personal letter from a specific person? (ie. I'm writing a personal letter from me, to ... a huge list of people)
- Is it a personal letter to a specific person? (ie. I'm writing this email to you, personally)

Am I wrong to react to all these emails? The only personal part of them is that they've mail-merged my name from the account data into a mass-market emails, is this personal? Again, obviously *someone* (that someone being a *person*) wrote these email, but is this "personal letters"?

Comment: I haven't encountered this usage, but I suspect that it's just dishonesty. It's like the junk-mail that's marked on the outside with "important information about your car insurance" (meaning "we don't know anything about your current car insurance, but would like to sell you a different one") or "mail carrier: please deliver directly to _____" (meaning "mail carrier: please ignore this bit and look at the destination address, as you always do").

Comment: @ruakh I quite agree. While a 'personal letter' would normally refer to a letter that is not a 'business letter', in this case, it seems that the term is being used in a deliberately misleading way.

Answer (score 1):

Before office technology had got to the point of enabling businesses to spam their customers with mail-merged 'personalized' letters, a personal letter was one that was written from one individual to another (or sometimes to an organization).

An online [letter-writing guide](http://www.goodletterwriting.com/personal-letters.html) sums up their typical content thus:

> They differ from formal types in that they can be used to express personal feelings, and depending on the relationship between the sender and receiver do not require formal concise language.

I agree with your commenters' remarks: the emails you received describe themselves as 'personal letters' while being anything but.

Answer (score 1):

In the context in which you present, it's a matter of persuasive rhetoric.

**When an employee of a firm sends correspondence to a customer or potential customer and the contents thereof seemingly have nothing to do with commerce, the connotation is personal.**

For example, this is a kind of *personal letter*

To: You

From: Sneaky Marketing Co.

Subject: A Personal Letter from Us to You ...

Dear You,

During these holiday times, all of us at Sneaky Marketing Company would like to wish you a very Merry Christmas and a Happy New Year.

Signed,

Mr. "We're Really Trying to Butter You Up in Hopes of Selling You Stuff by Feigning to be your Friend or Kin"